# Is UPDATE allowed before PRACK is not received from the network to the earlier 18x(Reliable Provisional Response)

Tags: sip

Invite carries offer from the network.
Can we send Update with sdp before the PRACK for first 18x is pending from the network, 18x sent was reliable provisional response?

RFC 3261 says 
  "After the first reliable provisional response for a request has been
   acknowledged, the UAS MAY send additional reliable provisional
   responses.  The UAS MUST NOT send a second reliable provisional
   response until the first is acknowledged.  After the first, it is
   RECOMMENDED that the UAS not send an additional reliable provisional
   response until the previous is acknowledged.  The first reliable
   provisional response receives special treatment because it conveys
   the initial sequence number.  If additional reliable provisional
   responses were sent before the first was acknowledged, the UAS could
   not be certain these were received in order."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRACK and UPDATE requests are both extensions to the core SIP RFC so there is no guarantee that they will be widely supported. I'd expect support for the UPDATE request in particular to be pretty limited in among various SIP implementations.

Looking at the [UPDATE request RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3311) there is no requirement that PRACK requests be supported or that the UAS must wait for a PRACK before sending an UPDATE request. So the answer to your question is no the UAS does not have to wait for a PRACK before sending any UPDATE requests.

There are rules in the UPDATE RFC that state how UPDATE requests are handled if there are outstanding offers that have been sent in a PRACK request but that's a different thing,

Answer (score 0):

As per  [RFC 6337](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6337#section-4.2) section 4.2, UAC should not send update if PRACK is still not received. Even though it is regarding reINVITE, I think it is relevant in your case also